# Placing data from sql table to userform and make some field to readonly and allow edit to remaining in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am a beginner in asp.net .now I am creating a website in Asp.net .And I would like to place a set of data from sql table to user form. And I want to make some data as read only in user form and user can edit remaining data .then a button click will cause to update the edited data in the same table.

i found many article for querying data from sql and updating the data.my problem is to place the data in the form and make the some data like "employee-id " as read only to user.and allow remaining data to edit.

any idea or solution will be so helpful.

Comment: which controls are you used to show result like using textbox or anything else

Comment: Is it an MVC site or a Web Forms one? If it's MVC, you might use that kind of thing: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m."employee-id,new{@readonly="readonly"})`. For other constraints, consider using Data Annotations that works well with MVC and Entity Framework.

Comment: I am using web form in asp.

Comment: how you are showing data.I mean using textbox,label or any other way